# Multi Series Ext Chart JS

Tags: c#, extjs

In Ext.Charts, i want to create a multi series chart (line + bar in one chart) that gets data in its store from C#.

Is that possible?  Is there an example that you can please show to explain how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely possible! You have an example graph with line + bar in extJS demo pages itself: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/chart/charts.html (Refer the last chart with line and bar)

Regarding fetching data from C#.. All you need is a URL that will send you the data (XML or JSON). So, you can have java,C#,python, PHP or any other server side technology.

ExtJs uses stores to hold info, you need to have a store, load data into it and associate the store with the chart to render the data.

**PS:** I have a series of tutorials at my blog - http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-extjs-charts.html

**UPDATE**
I have explained how to handle charts with series in my blog. Have a look at the above link. I have a similar chart (only think is I am using line chart). My Json array returned from server side is:

```
[
{month:'Jan', sales: 2000, rev: 3000},{month:'Feb', sales: 1800, rev: 2900},
{month:'Mar', sales: 1500, rev: 3100},{month:'Apr', sales: 2150, rev: 2500},
{month:'May', sales: 2210, rev: 2700},{month:'Jun', sales: 2250, rev: 2900},
{month:'Jul', sales: 2370, rev: 2800},{month:'Aug', sales: 2500, rev: 2600},
{month:'Sep', sales: 3000, rev: 3400},{month:'Oct', sales: 2580, rev: 3250},
{month:'Nov', sales: 2100, rev: 3000},{month:'Dec', sales: 2650, rev: 3300}
]
```

In this I have two data (sales, revenue) and one axis info (month). So, you need to set your xAxis as month and the series info as sales and rev.

Binding your store with server side is done through JsonReader or Proxy ExtJS objects. You need to specify from which URL you need to get the data.

Comment: thanks i have got it to work with JSON javascript store but i want the data to be a dictionary in C#

Comment: i have a chart. chart has 2 data series. one line, one bar. i want the data to be based on ext:store control. ext:store has three properties. 1st property: x axis name, 2nd property is y axis values for line chart and 3rd property is y axis values for bar char.  i want to bind ext:store to data from c#.

Comment: @AbdelOlakara is it possible to use two axis one on the right for the bar and one on the left for the line?